# Placing 2 adsense vertically with css

Tags: html, css, css-float, adsense

I'm trying to place 2 adsense ads vertically (i.e. under each other) but at the moment both ads are shown next to each other (horizontally). Any suggestions where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="wrap" >
<div id="right-float1">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Page_right_top_300x250_ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

<div id="ad5-right-float">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Page_right_top_300x250_ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
#wrap {
position: relative;
min-width: 980px; 
margin: 0 auto; 

}

#right-float1 {
float: right;
position: relative;
min-height: 1000px;
}

# right-float2 {
float: right;
position: relative;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#right-float2 
{
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   clear:right;
}
```

try this one.